# Find all layout constraint issues while debugging

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way I can find all UI related constraint issues while debugging my iOS app. I recently faced an issue in my production app that a UI constraint was failing and it caused an issue only on iPhone 8+. I didn't realise it while testing as even though that constraint failed on all devices, it still worked on my testing device.

Is there a strict mode which I can enable for development which would crash the app on any device if there is any constraint issue ?

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to modes. You can debug app in "Release" mode by editing scheme for "Run" and select "Release". If you can add crash logs that would elaborate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any unsatisfiable constraints will be reported in the console. If your console is too noisy, that's a separate problem, but if you really want to get slapped in the face, you can set a symbolic breakpoint:

[image: Adding a symbolic breakpoint to fire on unsatisfiable constraints]

Hitting a breakpoint will be more helpful than just crashing, since it gives you a chance to inspect the console to get details about the incorrect constraints.

Comment: Yeah this would work and I'm marking it as the correct answer, but would there still be a way to actually crash on debug apps ? because don't want to test while debugger always attached. Thanks!

Comment: No way that I know of, sorry. You can run UI tests in multiple simulated devices to help with coverage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict mode as such that will do it. Calculating constraints is done at runtime considering the existing device's size, resolution, etc. But you can test your app once in every size class before releasing to production. For example: iphone 5, iphone 6, iphone 10, 8plus.

Also while running the app, check for the logs and search for "NSLayoutConstraint". If there is any constraint failing, you will see those in logs when you search for that string.